Double Sided Printing Combines Multiple Copies Together
I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 and whenever I print double sided it will string multiple copies together for odd pages and not keep them collated i.e. separate.
Printing odd pages will combine the last page and the first page of the next set together which makes it frustrating.  I have had to literally put in a blank page by editing the .pdf and adding a page to make it even so that the multiple prints are separate.
Also, if I am printing single page, the always sticky print double page setting, will cause the single page to print double sided when you want to print multiples but keep them separate.
These are usually .pdfs I am printing so I don't know if it is specific to .pdfs or not.

You could/should file *.pdf and for i in *.pdf ; do ; pdfinfo $i; done to find out if it's the  .pdf files.

I printed with Open Office and got the same results.
